# Can't switch language in Ubuntu 13.10 lock screen

Tags: keyboard-layout, lock-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and have two keyboard layouts installed (English and Hebrew).

If I forget the Hebrew as active language and the computer locks, I can't switch it back to English in the lock screen, and I have to click on "Switch User" as a workaround.

Comment: You can click the language icon to switch layouts. Also, there is an answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/368946/153594

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And I find out that you can switch between layouts by clicking on layout name on the right side of input field. 
I think this problem has the same couse as [that one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please do not add questions or comments as answers to other peoples questions. If you like to ask a new Question use the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) Button above. If you spend time on this site by answering questions or asking good questions, you can gain reputation and also comment on questions and answers from other people.

Comment: Sorry! I was confused by UI. Add answer button so big and orange. I just did not notice "add comment" link.

Comment: That's OK, Andrey. You're only seeing the "add comment" link now because you can only comment on your own posts. The ability to comment everywhere is a privilege to be unlocked, unfortunately, which means new users are sometimes forced to use an answer when a comment would be more appropriate.